# Trying To Make a Discord Bot - Error Role Not Found

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, roles

I have asked this question on the [Replit forum](https://ask.replit.com/t/help-with-a-discord-bot-function-add-role-by-text-trigger/17047/38) but the developers are unsure of the problem.

My friend and I want to add a function to our bot that gives a user the role `Baguette_Team`, and posts a message saying that they received the role if they post a message that says `I love baguettes!`.

## Code

```
import os, re, discord
from discord.ext import commands

DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")


client = 
commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents= discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print("message was: " + message.content)
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content == 'I love baguettes!':
        role = message.guild.get_role(1085983212855115887)
        #discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id="1085983212855115887")
        await message.author.add_roles(message.author, role, reason="You said the magic words!", atomic=True)
        await message.channel.send('So do I! In fact, I have given you the Baguette Team role!')

client.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

## Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/runner/Blockcoin-Bot/venv/lib/python 3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 22, in on_message
    await member.add_roles(role) 
  File "/home/runner/Blockcoin-BotIvenv/lib/python 3.10/site-packages/discord/member.py", line 1044, in add rotes
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason, eason)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: The error message is stating `role` is `NoneType`...with that I'd bet your call is wrong here because it returns nothing: `role = message.guild.get_role(1085983212855115887)` what happens when you print the `role` object after that line? -- I'd bet it's None

Comment: Yes, when I printed it I get `none`. The role id is correct, so I don’t know why it yields `none`

Comment: Does your bot have the required permissions ?

Comment: Yes, I had my friend enable every possible permission.

Comment: I've not used discord before so I'm just adding thoughts...in your code you have commented out below, you have the ID quoted (i.e. a string): `#discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id="1085983212855115887")`....does this output None as well? In some APIs I use the difference between string and int matter. In your failing code you pass in an integer, what happens when you turn it to a string?

Comment: Still returns `none`.

Comment: Please refrain from posting image errors. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: I posted an image because I could not copy and paste the error. I have changed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What the error most likely means

The error most likely means that the role wasn't found, or you're not adding the role properly. Assuming you have the right role ID,

### How to get a role

The way that you're getting the role is correct. In the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=role#discord.Guild.get_role) you get the role from the guild by `Guild.get_role(role_id)` (non-async command).

You could alternatively use [`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=utils#discord.utils.get) if that isn't working.

### How to add a role to a user

This is where the issue likely is. You're using the right command, but the parameters are incorrect. In the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=utils#discord.Member.add_roles) it shows that you use the following: `await add_roles(*roles, reason=None, atomic=True)`. However, you put `message.author` as the first positional parameter. Instead, change it to the role.

For example:

```
await message.author.add_roles(role, reason="You said the magic words!", atomic=True)
```

Just remove the `message.author` from the positional arguments.